# Which k-means cluster should I assign a record to, when the euclidean distance between the record and both centroids are the same?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I am dealing with k-means clustering 6 records. I am given the centroids and K=3. I have only 2 features. My given centroids are known. as I have only 3 features I am assuming as x,y points and I have plotted them.

Having the points mapped on an x and y axis, finding the euclidean distance I found that lets say (8,6) belongs to the my first cluster. However for all other records, the euclidean distance between the records 2 nearest centroids are the same. So lets say the point (2,6) should belong to the centroid (2,4) or (2,8)?? Or (5,4) belongs to (2,4) or (8,4)??

Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

The objective of k-means is to minimize variance.

Therefore, you should assign the point to that cluster, where variance increases the least. Even when cluster centers are at the same distance, the increase in variance by assigning the point can vary, because the cluster center will move due to this change. This is one of the ideas of the very fast Hartigan-Wong algorithm for k-means (as opposed to the slow textbook algorithm).

Comment: Anony. Thank you for reply. I am not sure what you mean by variance. my data points are (8,4), (5,4), (2,4 ), (2,6), (2,8), (8,6). My centroids are (8,4) cluster 1, (2,4) cluster 2 and  (2,8)cluster 3. If you simply just scatter plot u'll see how it will look like. So which cluster do (2,6) and (5,4) belong to based on the variance you talked about? I really appreciate your reply. The only thing I am sure is that (8,6) belong to cluster 1. But I still can not decide for the 2 remaining records I am given the cluster centroids,  different thanknown k means which assigns centroids randomly

Comment: Try both, and compute the cost function. It most likely is not the same. For the details, see the work of Hartigan and Wong. The change in variance is not to be explained in a few lines here.